# How can I import UnixFileAttributes?

Tags: java, attributes, view

When I execute this snippet:

```
 FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
for (String s : fs.supportedFileAttributeViews())
{
System.out.println(s);
}
```

I get this result: "basic owner user **unix** dos posix"

Then when I try actually to use UnixFileAttributeView() it appears to not exist.
I imported the whole package by importing `java.nio.file.attribute.*;`, but also tried to import directly `java.nio.file.attributes.UnixFileAttributeView;` and it appears to not exist.

Whereas I am able to import all the other attributeViews I get out of `fs.supportedFileAttributeViews()`.

Do you know why it happens? And moreover how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs

> [PosixFileAttributeView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html) – Extends the basic attribute view with
>   attributes supported on file systems that support the POSIX family of
>   standards, such as UNIX. These attributes include file owner, group
>   owner, and the nine related access permissions.

Comment: What about this? src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileAttributeView.java ? What kind of library is that? and why did they have to create a specific class if there was already PosixFileAttributeView?

Comment: That is part of openjdk so it may not be present in other JDK version. Not sure why they came up with that, may be just another example of multiple implementation taking different route

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to be possible to import it.

By googling you can find some source for OpenJDK implementation.

I have found the simplest way to access the data to be:

```java
Files.getAttribute(file.toPath, "unix:uid")
```

You have these options at least:

```
dev
ino
mode
uid
gid
size
atime
mtime
ctime
```

Of course you should check `Files.getFileStore(file.toPath).supportsFileAttributeView("unix")` first.

Answer (score 0):

It's not bundled with java 1.7, however, you can read its attributes as shown in previous comments.

Additional note is that you can refer to backport_project_of_JSR203 and you can find an implementation of it:

https://code.google.com/p/jsr203-backport/source/browse/trunk/src/jsr203/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileAttributeView.java